# nonlinear regression in R with multiple data sets

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-optimization

I am learning R and currently using it for non linear regression (which I am also learning).
I have two sets of data (duration of an operation on different machines) and I am able to find a good non linear regression for each of these sets.
Now, I would like to find the best regression that minimise the sum of both residual sum-of-squares.

Here is what I have :

```
A <- c(1:5)
B <- c(100, 51, 32, 24, 19)
C <- c(150, 80, 58, 39, 29)

df <- data.frame (A,B,C)

f <- B ~ k1/A + k2
g <- C ~ k1/A + k2

n <- nls(f, data = df, start = list(k1=10, k2=10))
p <- nls(g, data = df, start = list(k1=10, k2=10))
n
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: B ~ k1/A + k2
#   data: df
#     k1      k2 
#101.595  -1.195 
# residual sum-of-squares: 2.619

#Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.568e-07

p
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: C ~ k1/A + k2
#   data: df
#     k1      k2 
#148.044   3.593 
# residual sum-of-squares: 54.19

#Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.803e-07
```

k1 and k2 constant are (of course) different for both sets (B and C), I am wondering how I could manage to find a particular k1 and a particular k2 that produce the 'best' solution for both data sets.

Hope my explanation will be understandable. Otherwise, what I'm trying to find is sometimes (at least [here](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/curve-fitting/index.htm?reg_how_global_nonlinear_regressio.htm)) called global non linear regression.

EDIT : I would also like to know how can I tell R to avoid negative values for a specific parameter. In this case, I would like k2 to be positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want identical parameters, you should just pool your data:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Y=c(df$B,df$C), X=rep(df$A, 2))
p <- nls(Y ~ k1/X + k2, 
         data = df2, 
         start = list(k1=10, k2=10), 
         lower = c(0, 0), 
         algorithm = "port")
summary(p)

#  Formula: Y ~ k1/X + k2
#  
#  Parameters:
#    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#  k1  124.819     18.078   6.904 0.000124 ***
#    k2    1.199      9.781   0.123 0.905439    
#  ---
#    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#  
#  Residual standard error: 16.59 on 8 degrees of freedom
#  
#  Algorithm "port", convergence message: both X-convergence and relative convergence (5)
```

**Edit:**

If you want one parameter to be equal and one to vary, you could use a mixed effects model. However, I don't know how to specify constraints for that (I believe that is not a simple task, but could possibly be achieved by reparameterization).

```
library(nlme)

library(reshape2)
df3 <- melt(df, id.vars="A")

r <- nlme(value ~ k1/A + k2, 
          data = df3, 
          start = c(k1=10, k2=10), 
          fixed = k1 + k2 ~1,
          random = k2 ~ 1|variable)

summary(r)
#  Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
#  Model: value ~ k1/A + k2 
#  Data: df3 
#  AIC      BIC    logLik
#  83.11052 84.32086 -37.55526
#  
#  Random effects:
#    Formula: k2 ~ 1 | variable
#                k2 Residual
#  StdDev: 12.49915 7.991013
#  
#  Fixed effects: k1 + k2 ~ 1 
#         Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
#  k1 124.81916  9.737738  7 12.818086  0.0000
#  k2   1.19925 11.198211  7  0.107093  0.9177
#  Correlation: 
#         k1    
#  k2 -0.397
#  
#  Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
#    Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
#  -1.7520706 -0.5273469  0.2746039  0.5235343  1.4971808 
#  
#  Number of Observations: 10
#  Number of Groups: 2 

coef(r)
#          k1        k2
#  B 124.8192 -10.81835
#  C 124.8192  13.21684
```

Comment: So I guess 'lower=c(0,0)' are minimum values for k1 and k2 ? What about the "port" algorithm ? ok I'll google that one :)

Comment: Is it always the way one should do a nonlinear regression on multiple data sets? What if I want to have k1 shared for both data sets and k2 can be specific?

Comment: @claferri Yes, `lower` specifies the constraints. If you need lower or upper bounds, you have to use the "port"  algorithm with `nls`. Read `help("nls")`.

Comment: @ Roland with nlme, is it possible to specify that k2 must be positiv? Could you explain briefly the 'fixed' and 'random' syntax too?

Comment: It seems SO suppress "@Roland" in my comments, had to put space between @ and Roland ... weird!

Comment: @claferri It's supressed because I get notified of comments to my answer anyway. As I wrote in the answer, I don't know a way to explicitly specify constraints in `nlme`. If you are not familiar with mixed effects models this is not the place to explain them. The syntax is explained in the function's documentation.

Comment: In fact, I'm trying to modify my model to add a k3 parameter which should be dataset specific like k2, but I can't find a way to add it in 'fixed' and 'random', nlme documentation is not clear enough for me, I keep getting errors.

Comment: Something like `nlme(value ~ k1/A + k2 + k3*A, data = df3, start = c(k1=10, k2=10, k3=10), fixed = k1 + k2 + k3 ~1,random = k2 + k3 ~ 1|variable)`?

Comment: That's what I tried, I guess the error means something else. Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: Hard to say without the error message. Could be convergence problems or overfitting or a number of other problems.

Comment: I'm trying `nlme(value ~ k1/(k3*A) + k2, data = df3, start = c(k1=10, k2=10, k3=10), fixed = k1 + k2 + k3 ~1,random = k2 + k3 ~ 1|variable)` and I guess this is the kind of things I can't do with nlme. The error is something like "the reduction factor at each stage is lowered below the minimum step to PNLS" (my error is in french, thus I'm not sure about the "PNLS" traduction).

Comment: @claferri This problem has nothing to do with `nlme`. `k1/(k3*A) + k2` can be simplified to `k4/A + k2`. It's mathematically not possible to separate `k1` and `k3`.

Comment: That's what I was guessing, but I thought maybe the fact that k1 was global and k3 wasn't may change the problem... My math background seems to be weak :). Hopefully, I see why this doesn't change anything now! :)